# How to add tolerance for time period using assert command in TestNG tool

Tags: java, testng

I am doing regression testing.
In my Aplication I am giving `assertEquals()` command for time period which is in miliseconds.But it has very small changes time period and my testcase failed.So I want to add Tolerance for 10milisec. How to add Tolerance?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this pseudo code:

```
bool public verifyWithTolerance(timeStamp) 
{
    lowerEnd = 500 miliseconds;
    higherEnd = 1000 miliseconds;
    if (timeStamp > 500 && timeStamp < 1000)
    {
        return True;
    }
    else {return False;}
}

assertTrue(verifyWithTolerance(timeStampYouWantToVerify))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AssertJ](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) which has the expected assertion:

```
assertThat(duration).isCloseTo(expectedDuration, offset(10));
```